# Error in parsing XML file using Python's ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to import an XML using ElementTree

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Object_Detection_Script.py", line 3, in <module>
  tree = ET.parse('text.xml')
  File "ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 20, column 6
```

Here's a part of my XML:

```
<Stream canTime="729785232" itcMsgCounter="39506" pcTime1="729209" sourceInfo="29.00" streamNumber="5.000" streamRefIndex="22090" vehIndexUsed="0" versionInfo="41240">
    <vision_failsafes blurImageFailsafe="false" blurredImageSeverityLevel="0" ddrRamCrcFailure="false" flrMisalignment="false" foggySpotsSeverityLevel="0" frameIndex="0" fullBlockageSeverityLevel="0" heavyRainFailsafe="false" imageIndex="0" invalidAhbcSensitivityParams="false" invalidSpdYawDetected="false" lowSunSeverityLevel="0" lowVisibilitySeverityLevel="0" outOfCalibrationSeverityLevel="0" outOfFocusSeverityLevel="0" partialSolidBlockageFailsafe="false" radarCommErrorCounter="0" radarMisalignSeverityLevel="0" radarVisCorrelationFailsafe="false" rccMisalignment="false" rollAngleFailsafe="false" selfGlareSeverityLevel="0" smearImageSeverityLevel="0" smearedSpotsSeverityLevel="0" splashesSeverityLevel="0" spotRaysSeverityLevel="0" sunRaySeverityLevel="0"/>
    <extraInfo>
```

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysskp.png)

Comment: your file is probably corrupt, but since you're not showing it... and it's not a programming problem in that case. did you check at line 20 column 6?

Comment: Is your file correct?

Comment: Your error says mismatched tag. What isn't clear about that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to XML and Python, and the XML document is generated from another document using a Lua script. It's around 500 thousand lines long. I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Comment: @MohamedAmeen Showing everything up through line 20, column 6 would be a good start.

Comment: @jwodder I've added a screenshot to the question description. the 20 line are too long to be written in a comment.

Comment: Does the xml have a root tag? If not that would be the reason!

Comment: Sounds like you need to debug the Lua script.

Comment: I can't add the first 20 lines to the question, this is too much code to be submitted as a question. It says: "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details".